# When was ADX permission created

Tags: azure-data-explorer, role-based-access-control

I have added a [role-based permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/manage-database-security-roles) to my ADX database using [`Add-AzKustoDatabasePrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.kusto/add-azkustodatabaseprincipal).

```
Add-AzKustoDatabasePrincipal `
    -ClusterName MyCluster `
    -DatabaseName MyDatabase `
    -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup `
    -Value (@{
        Name="Serious Q. Programmer";
        Role="Admin";
        Type="User";
        Email="serious.q@programmer.biz"
    })
```

For audit scrutiny, I would like to prove when and by whom the role was last configured.

`.show database MyDatabase permissions` lists information about the role, but sadly no metadata around creation. Likewise, the "MyDatabase > Permissions" web UI has role info but no timestamps.

The cluster-level ["Activity log" web UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log) shows an "`Add database principals action`" event...

[image: mycluster > Activity log]

...but strangely, the `AzureActivity` OMS table does not contain a log record for the principal creation (despite containing records for all other events I see in the Activity Log UI at this time).

```
AzureActivity
| distinct OperationNameValue
```

Where does the log record for principal creation live and how do I query it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `OMS` or `AzureActivity`, but if it happened during the last 365d, you should be able to see it in the cluster/database [journal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/journal).

you can, for example, include the following filters `... | where Event has_any('ADD-DATABASE','DROP-DATABASE') and Event has_any('ADMINS','VIEWERS','USERS')`

Comment: Worth noting that for permissions added from the web UI, the `User` attribute in `.show journal` is not the expected email address of the User but an `AAD app id` - which reduces the usefulness of this channel as an audit log.

Comment: Additionally, if a principal permission is removed from a DB, the _entire history_ of that principal's grants is obfuscated from this channel until the principal is re-added.